# $H$-subrepresentations where $H=\langle(123)\rangle\subset S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> Let $\rho$ be the irreducible two-dimensional representation of $S_3$, realised as the space
>
> $$V = \{(x, y, z) : x + y + z = 0\}$$
>
> of the permutation representation. Let $H =\langle (123)\rangle \subset S_3$. Then $\rho_H$ is reducible (as it must be: all irreducible representations of $H\cong C_3$ are one dimensional).

Indeed, let $v = (1, \omega, \omega^2)$ and $w = (1, \omega^2, \omega)$ where $\omega =
e^{2\pi i/3}$. Then $\langle v\rangle $ and $\langle w\rangle$ are $H$-subrepresentations of $V$ with $V = \langle v\rangle\oplus\langle w\rangle$.

The action of $H$ on $\langle v\rangle $ is through the character taking $(123)$ to $\omega$, and the action on $\langle w\rangle$ is through the character taking $(123)$ to $\omega^{-1}$.

Why are $\langle v\rangle $ and $\langle w\rangle$ $H$-subrepresentations? Also, how do we know the action of $H$ on $\langle v\rangle $ and $\langle w\rangle $ to be as described above?

Thank you :)

Comment: You were given that $S_3$ acts on $V$ by permuting the coordinates. Now apply that to the permutation $(123)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks very much! :)